# How to get all the property and values in the Request variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, reflection

I know that I can loop through each key value pair in Request headers variables as follow

```
 foreach (var key in Request.Headers.AllKeys)
 {
    // headers += key + "=" + Request.Headers[key] + "<br/>";
 }
```

Similarly I can get all the key value pair in Request.Browser as follow

```
HttpBrowserCapabilities bc = Request.Browser;
foreach (DictionaryEntry p in bc.Capabilities)
{
   // p.Key 
   //p.Value
}
```

Now I want to know that can I loop through every possible values in Request variable and if there is another key value inside it then get all the information.

### Edit

Can I use reflection to get all the list of property and subpropery.

Comment: What kind of request variable you want?

Comment: I want know information about the browser and the OS information. But I want to see all the options.

Answer (score 1):

[HttpRequest.Params](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.params.aspx) provides you with the raw data of all the Query-string parameters, Form fields, Cookies and Server variables. Pretty much everything sent by the client's user-agent!

Comment: thanks for your solution. But I want to loop every thing inside request variable.

Comment: What's the point? Given that all you need is the data sent from client's browser, your best bet is `HttpRequest.Params`. That caontains all data sent from client's user-agent, nothing more, nothing less